# Unhandled rejection on Sequelize using ES7 async function

Tags: async-await, sequelize.js, ecmascript-2016

I am having this error when getting a ValidationFailed of a Sequelize.js model:

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeValidationError: Validation error: The Login is not a valid email

But this Unhandled rejection comes up only when working with ES7 `async` functions, see this code:

```
export async function create (req, res) {
  try {
    res.json({ admin : await Admin.create(req.body) });
  } catch (err) {
    const message = {
      Login : err.errors.map(error => error.message),
    };
    res.status(400).json({ error : 'ValidationFailed', message : message });
  }
}
```

But, when I use the ES5 promise format, it doesn't throw the exception.

```
export function create (req, res) {
  Admin.create(req.body)
    .then(admin => {
      res.json({ admin : admin });
    }, err => {
      const message = {
        Login : err.errors.map(error => error.message),
      };
      res.status(400).json({ error : 'ValidationFailed', message : message });
    });
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To wait for a promise to resolve with async functions, you need to use the `await` keyword.

```
export async function create (req, res) {
  try {
    await res.json({ admin : await Admin.create(req.body) });
 // ^^^^ very important to include
  } catch (err) {
    const message = {
      Login : err.errors.map(error => error.message),
    };
    res.status(400).json({ error : 'ValidationFailed', message : message });
  }
}
```

The error is no longer in scope without the `async` keyword, and becomes an unhandled exception.

Comment: I am using it. Check on the `res.json({ admin : await Admin.create(req.body) });` line.